# Creating custom dataset for Pose estimation using blender and pybullet

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, dataset, pytorch

I am trying to create my own dataset for pose estimation of YCB colliding objects. The Pose of the object (obj.location and obj.rotation of blender objects used for rendering) is different from the ground truth. I know this because I tried to overlay the object model with the Pose saved from the blender and it does not aline with the object. Did any face a similar issue? any idea how to get the ground truth pose.